# How to send and convert back UTC timestamp between iOS app and PhP API?

Tags: php, ios, date

Me & my PhP developer facing issues with converting date & time.

What I'm doing:

In my app, I'm performing activities each day and that will be saved into the server. To know date and time of particular activity, I'm passing UTC timestamp (based on a date).

What PhP developer doing:

He's creating a date (in `yyyy-MM-dd` format) from  UTC timestamp (which I passed into the API). And also storing the actual time stamp in another column.

Here's the problem, in my app, when I'm trying to fetch activities based on particular date, he's grouping activities based on the date he stored. And will return me result set.

But here's the problem I faced,

What I passed to the server isn't coming back.

For e.g.

goodTimestamp = 1442342364 (what I passed)

badTimestamp = 1442275200 (what converted based on a date stored on database on server)

If you link to [this](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm) site and check convert timestamp to a date then you'll get to know that both are showing this date.

> good date = Tue, 15 Sep 2015 18:39:24 GMT
>
> bad date = Tue, 15 Sep 2015 00:00:00 GMT

because of this, I'm getting a wrong result. I performed an activity on `16th Sep 2015 at 12:09 am`. But I'm not getting the proper result.

What we should do to having same date & time by continuing the same flow (from app)?

---

I've created a test code to check whether the date is correct or not.

```
NSString *badTimestamp = @"1442275200";
NSString *goodTimestamp = @"1442342364";
NSDate *goodDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[goodTimestamp doubleValue]];
NSDate *badDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[badTimestamp doubleValue]];

NSDateComponents *goodComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear ) fromDate:goodDate];
NSDateComponents *badComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear ) fromDate:badDate];
NSLog(@"good : %ld - %ld - %ld", goodComponents.day, goodComponents.month, goodComponents.year);
NSLog(@"bad : %ld - %ld - %ld", badComponents.day, badComponents.month, badComponents.year);

> 2015-09-09 19:36:30.918 MyApp[23827:292047] good : 16 - 9 - 2015
> 2015-09-09 19:36:31.380 MyApp[23827:292047] bad : 15 - 9 - 2015
```

Here's the PhP code which convert timestamp to a date.

```
date('Y-m-d', 'timestamp');
```

Comment: Please add php code too.

Comment: could be something as silly as `$good = time(); $bad = mktime(0, 0, 0)`. so, yes... show the php code.

Comment: Sounds like the date stored on the server doesn't include the time, which is why when converting them back to timestamps, it's always at midnight...

Comment: @MarcB, added PhP code.

Comment: @Robert, I've added PhP code, please check and let me know the correct way to get this done.

Comment: looks like you're simply dealing with the fact that one system is generating a date-only, and the other system is generating date+time. there's nothing you can do to fix this, short of forcing both to act the same way: both do date-only, or both do date+time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution that we've (me & pHp developer) integrated together is to store a timestamp with date & time both. At the time of returning back, set the result based on a timestamp available. Now everything working fine at my end. Thanks to the people who've looked after here for my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your php code doesn't include time in date. The right way would be

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 'timestamp');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my PhP developer is taking only `Y-m-d`  to do a comparison of dates easily. As a final result, he'll send me an object contains a list of activities within an array. Is there any other way if I don't want a time.

Comment: Why taking out the time would affect dates comparison? If one date is lower than another, it is still lower.

Comment: Yes, but there's multiple activities on same day.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you getting activities for each day at once?  Then what exactly is your issue? What is the result you're getting. Can you show your SQL query as well?